# How to avoid Pathologic module to change a javascript src value?

Tags: nodes, uri

I need to insert a javascript code in a textarea field of a node. This one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.avaibook.com/js/avaibook.js"></script>
```

The problem is that this line becomes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="about:blank"></script>
```

The real source value: `http://www.avaibook.com/js/avaibook.js` is replaced by `about:blank`.

I already know that the pathologic module is the cause (if I disable it it works fine), but can't disable since I need it for other purposes.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding Javascript in your template files by using

```
<?php
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/mytheme.js');
?>
```

also this works in modules etc as explained here: http://drupal.org/node/304255

sometimes it is comfortable to add whole JavaScript inline:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
   // Your stuff
   })      
', 'inline');
```

Hope that helps avoid that module behaviour.

Comment: since the js shows a booking calendar I need to put the script in the middle the body text, then I'd like to have the option to insert it directly in this field.

Comment: But did you try to add your script inline as i suggested ? That way you are avoiding referencing a source.

Comment: I haven't see your lines for adding it inline. It works, thanks

Comment: I added it 1 minute after i submitted answer, probably that's the reason :)